# Itunes doesn't play an entire albume

Tags: itunes, album

In older versions iTunes played automatically the entire songs in an albume when I selected and pressed the play button. Now it only plays the first song then stops. What do I need to do to play the whole album?

Comment: is this relevant? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230250/gray-itunes-album-tracks/230252#230252 You don't say whether you're on iDevice or computer, so it's hard to say