# Some songs don't play in iTunes on macOS

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

Some of the songs in my iTunes library refuse to play. When I double click on them, nothing happens. When I play the song before it and then skip over to the next song, it actually skips the song and thus goes forward 2 songs. There is nothing different about this song, it's part of an album where every song plays just fine, it's not unchecked or anything.

When I find this song in my Finder and play it through VLC, it plays absolutely fine, no problem at all.

I am not using Apple Music, but I do have iTunes Match. This song has the status "matched" and is downloaded to my computer. Removing the downloading and fetching it again doesn't help.

Comment: Are you sure you're not seeing this... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230250/gray-itunes-album-tracks/230252#230252

Comment: Yep, like I said: it's not unchecked. It doesn't show gray, and most importantly, it doesn't play even when double clicking.

Comment: Could it be a file that has accidentally been changed to a duration of one second or less?  Or, if you Show Info and go to the Options tab, does it have a stop time set?